# How can I make a mapped type retain its types when accessing a variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm trying to retain the types of an object with string keys with values that can be either two types. A simple example:

```
type Option1 = number

type Option2 = string

interface Options {
  readonly [key: string]: Option1 | Option2
}

const options: Options = { test: 1, world: "true"}
```

I would like it, where if I do `options.test`, since it's `readonly`, it's able to infer that it *is* a number.

Current code:

```
interface Option<T, R> {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly type: R;
    value: T;
    readonly defaultValue: T;
  }

  type TextOption = Option<string, "text">;
  type BooleanOption = Option<boolean, "boolean">;
  type ColorOption = Option<string, "color">
  type NumberOption = Option<number, "number">
  type Options = { readonly [key: string] : TextOption | BooleanOption | ColorOption | NumberOption }

  interface RenderSystem {
    name: string,
    options: Options
  }

  interface CanvasRenderSystem extends RenderSystem {
    type: "canvas";
    render: (value: string, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, options: Options) => void;
    currentCanvas?: HTMLCanvasElement;
  }

  interface TextRenderSystem extends RenderSystem {
    type: "text";
    lineSpacing: string;
    tracking: string;
    render: (value: string, options: Options) => string;
  }

  type AnyRenderSystem = TextRenderSystem | CanvasRenderSystem

  const renderSystems: AnyRenderSystem[] = [{
    type: "canvas",
    name: "Simple Image",
    render: (value, canvas, options) => {
      clearCanvas(canvas)
      renderCanvas({ 
        value, 
        foregroundColor: options.foregroundColor.value as string,
        backgroundColor: options.backgroundColor.value as string
      }, canvas)
    },
    options: {
      foregroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Foreground Color", value: "#000000", defaultValue: "#000000" },
      backgroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Background Color", value: "#ffffff", defaultValue: "#ffffff" }
    }
  }]
```

When I call the first renderSystem's render method, the renderSystem's type is defined as a CanvasRenderSystem

Any improvements non-related to the question can be left in the comments -- I haven't really improved on the rest of the types yet. As shown in the code, I'm using `as string`, but I'm looking for a better way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given constraints, you'll have to pull out the fullstops and all the TS knowledge possible to do something like this. I have done this many times but you'll need to know the following:

- [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)
- [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)
- [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)
- and abusing [function inferences](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference) to create a wrapper function

Here is a simple example, answering your simple question

```js
type ReturnCreateOptions<T extends Options> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? number : string
}

const createOptions = <T extends Options>(o: T): ReturnCreateOptions<T> => o as any

const optionsWrapped = createOptions({test: 1, world: "true"})

type testb1 = typeof optionsWrapped.test
//  ^? `type testb1 = number`
type testb2 = typeof optionsWrapped.world
//  ^? `type testb2 = string`
```

Then we can expand it out to your given code

```js
interface Option<T, R> {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly type: R;
  value: T;
  readonly defaultValue: T;
}

type TextOption = Option<string, "text">;
type BooleanOption = Option<boolean, "boolean">;
type ColorOption = Option<string, "color">
type NumberOption = Option<number, "number">
type OptionsAdvanced = { readonly [key: string] : TextOption | BooleanOption | ColorOption | NumberOption }

type ReturnCreateOptionsAdvanced<T extends OptionsAdvanced> = 
  {
    [K in keyof T]: 
      T[K]['type'] extends 'text'
        ? TextOption
      : T[K]['type'] extends 'boolean'
        ? BooleanOption
      : T[K]['type'] extends 'color'
        ? ColorOption
      : NumberOption
  }

type RenderSystemParam<OptionsType extends ReturnCreateOptionsAdvanced<any>> = 
// Default Render System Key/Value
({
  name: string
  options: OptionsType
} & ({ //Canvas
  type: 'canvas';
  render: (value: string, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, options: OptionsType) => void
  currentCanvas?: HTMLCanvasElement
} | { // Text
  type: "text";
  lineSpacing: string;
  tracking: string;
  render: (value: string, options: OptionsType) => string;
}))[]

const createRenderSystems = <T extends ReturnCreateOptionsAdvanced<any>>(o: RenderSystemParam<T>): RenderSystemParam<T> => o;

//Mock renderCanvas function
const renderCanvas = (...args: any[]): void => undefined;

const renderSystems = createRenderSystems(
  [{
    type: "canvas",
    name: "Simple Image",
    render: (value, canvas, options) => {
      //clearCanvas(canvas)
      renderCanvas({ 
        value, 
        foregroundColor: options.foregroundColor.value,
        backgroundColor: options.backgroundColor.value //string | number | boolean? Huh?
      }, canvas)
    },
    options: {
      foregroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Foreground Color", value: "#000000", defaultValue: "#000000" },
      backgroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Background Color", value: "#ffffff", defaultValue: "#ffffff" },
      test: {type: 'wack'} //Error! That's because our options is wrong!
    }
  }]
)

const renderSystems2 = createRenderSystems(
  [{
    type: "canvas",
    name: "Simple Image",
    render: (value, canvas, options) => {
      //clearCanvas(canvas)
      renderCanvas({ 
        value, 
        foregroundColor: options.foregroundColor.value, //string! Hooray!
        backgroundColor: options.backgroundColor.value 
      }, canvas)
    },
    options: {
      foregroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Foreground Color", value: "#000000", defaultValue: "#000000" },
      backgroundColor: { type: "color", name: "Background Color", value: "#ffffff", defaultValue: "#ffffff" },
    }
  }]
)
```

View this example on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWghAhgZwKbQMIvQCgHYD2ALtAO4EBOA1gJZ4DmAlFLMFHUahQGaIDG6APIAHIjQJ5k0AN4toFVIgAmEgDYBPaAG0qqdQC5oyIhTr0AuobwBXALYAjLtAA+Rk2agBfKFD4Tj0ASi4pKGImL+0AC8MtCcxoYAjAA0ZJSqSoYARCbWqFnekFBE6sLo8USIidFxpagE3IHB-gB0FVDAwNDQAHoA-D6QoBAwcACqyGbQiNDc1nh8EXhkFIjCZRRxBNP21miz84sh0HTcXKgLHqNskCVl0ABKqETWFHgYCoic4SHIADwAFWgqAAHpw8EopD9-AA+GqyGDaADSJ2WunUDWgAMsWK0SPMwLBF0h0BsDicfVJdkcm0MxlMDC8gz8khIfE+32akhqgMJ4JJ0MkMJwBEMAMYhieLzeH0UnKW-wBcKicO2KGmeHUzP8JCCCoA6qt1qglDV2XLUILkDhpBUkqlyBQMtlcvlPMwirc6nFUMZ7NUYnd6o09b9DWsyko2r6iB0ur0Bl77hV7AAmGpBzGh-zh41Rx0ZOPdfqDYYsOAASWWGNe0D42HLNw4XF4AmggsBqQecIR3U+KjwGlJiFsqDp7gYAG45P21Jog5Lp4iAG6IVR5MVLvuKAdDpSoXjWVREABqa43WKXhWK3oBoKIgpqHfpZlSOXvWRhS6DCAIBFUih4I+MQdvYf4AYgeBvmB-6AZ+37ehg-6UMB7Zcn8L4MG+fiqJQn43vcABy1JcKhHZkjSb4UVw+FJkIXLIAAgkoq4LCa8LyDuc7aOi44MhY0Bivej6uPA4GASJmDIRQknEeSMlctA150Y8zyvO8HKWgxzGsQISi8vexJQtpLGQXpyrQHIvbdMiqLQOimLYoYcg2bi+JaAA5EGHkEoZEJSF594eS5rnQJSd5goKIXdGKeLmJ53m+US-nQB5MEQXgwWIqFYW-rBkFRdlNmxe5Xl1D5fJGalOGUFlOXdJSSG4QpSzRYJ0ByTShXdMpP5PBCXAAMrqMYqC2AACogqy2H8VoAt6fkklK6myl8WkKjpZkmn8kHqDCFlFgAIgeiBHiQ-X7psw2jbY0BInowBnuuqBQDach4COY5uPxcjZqEaEKvNZReNAABk0A2tAnRYHgq7IHIC7VZBcMeVunEDRQhg4Kuz18a+dbIyghgABIAgAsgAMjDcMAKIAaOeBEKkf3IGEDFA6gjDRHCy4EDQShyHwrwKIz1MoH0JPk1ThPIHTY0XLGkCeC4sSdFi94I3ULofmjqh0Kgg3CPwZh41OCOrHwtAMKb9BoyLl1YzjF6YfQzMMWzgN1FzKrfWYV6MIwWjmNqrJ1ppF1DSNnC2FIMQGclS1qTKmlWptbH6bt+0ipKxKRzdk3TYCMISqpGPXdHBcjkX3OBEucZkwQlvo5dYtSHMCytZALIBPbXCtzUOAtEPU30KzGrqEHJe8-zNfzPu3D60odddzqzd59HsdhxaEcUOXY3WnIWjWd0iNZPWsMoFkyQhR9o7ZINNC2MIAHQBWtiIPQ+TX0VveYxDTuoFSOfOGbsFTex7G1TofAIIUFbjgYBKAPQ5V-nA6QlkiquQAakNq3RuCUFQPQCgBA55NUoIYFmLQ8EKEIcQiEpCKAtCwTg6A9h+BUBoSQ6S5CGItFYZbDhdDpKMPPOgToLsVbUU2K4dKgFKTE2sAAC0TDlTwQCZZIJsqokKLNDDHxslQghRDOHNV0bUMo2QaoUCvsOO+0AsgADF8ECNNPQ6xADsgAGIAAMPjfHWPnqdY8T0LxZG8b4nxWQlLfxynw9hRjBEmNiKfSx1jb5fSyEgfh8SXHSTcSIzx3BClFP8SdM6wT0keKKcUqJbU7QyERh5UgbCPLK06DTCgRCKAAEIsQKK+B5KQjh6x7HQMQzYLMThSFIEQhgXSQqFB6sHSAHpfCr1-nvGO6YYjmjWjvDZB9ERHxCskmWV8b6fXvo-Z+6A34fy-iFX+jsRFqIvsgUBvxwEyEgcAaBihYEy3geotqKCAVoOYVg9B9VZhOOyfQ7hCpKEwtoUoehwjnqpDEROegPTiZ-lWOoOZGCbKxOcXCpoCKSWwqEQAyFoVVEE1eRonq0SbI6K+USgxpKuFJK1nYlJqQ0nZEcdQ7JUlmp5NxnYsJ4SSmHiCfkqV4SIk1KJZS5FZK0HJNyQKi5djMlxORWKvCqR3FSqqYU2VgTTwKtCea7gkStFFQWUpJZjAgA), play around for a bit to try to understand all that's happening here, at it is somewhat complex.

Notice that if the options key/value is incorrect, we won't get the right type at all. But if we get rid of it, it will work!

Comment: FYI you can simply return `T` in your `createOptions` type because TypeScript uses duck typing so it would know that `T` extends options if you used it later based upon the generic constraint.